# Spring Seccurity Java based Configuration not working. It will always show index.jsp page

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I am converting my simple demo project from bean configuration to pure java based configuration. there small problem some where but i cannot find where it occurs please help me. I use this tutorial for build my project
[Spring Security 4 Hello World Annotation+XML Example](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-hello-world-annotation-xml-example/)

but there small defferent between this project and my project that is project maven archetype my one is multi module maven project.

here is my project archetype

[image: maven archetype]

following files are the I used for do my configuration

This pom is the root pom and each module has there own poms. this pom is inside the sms module

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.geek</groupId>
<artifactId>sms</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>sms</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <warName>sms-web</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>smsweb</finalName>
</build>

<modules>
  <module>sms-core</module>
  <module>sms-web</module>
</modules>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


 </project>
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.geek.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.geek.*" )
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
                       = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.geek.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").roles("ADMIN");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");//dba have two roles.
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll() 
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
    .and().formLogin()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

}

}
```

SpringMvcInitializer.java

```
package com.geek.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

SpringSecurityInitializer.java

```
package com.geek.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.geek.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hi, Welcome to mysite. ");
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
    return "admin";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/db", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String dbaPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
    return "dba";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      if (auth != null){    
         new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
      }
      return "welcome";
   }

@RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
    return "accessDenied";
}

private String getPrincipal(){
    String userName = null;
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        userName = principal.toString();
    }
    return userName;
}

}
```

what was i expected is when i am trying to log into my application using this

http://localhost:8080/sms-web I need redirect to the login.jsp page or something any other page but this will redirect to the index.jsp.

when i am trying to run this sms-web.war using external tomcat and put my war file into webapps folder it will end up with error like this

```
 > uring scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
 SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further 
 details.
 11-Jun-2017 14:18:55.435 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal 
 ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sms-web]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(Ljava/util/List;)V
        at

org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178
)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

```
11-Jun-2017 14:18:55.435 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web 
application archive F:\Pe
rsonal\Cingle Eve\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\sms-web.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Cat
alina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sms-web]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 11-Jun-2017 14:18:55.455 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] 
 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web 
 application archive F:\Person
al\Cingle Eve\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\sms-web.war has finished in 
3,913 ms
```

What's wrong I did please help me to the find the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a mess in your dependencies mixing different spring versions. Try using dependencies below:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${mongo-driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-jsp-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-digester.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With following properties:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <mongo-driver.version>3.4.2</mongo-driver.version>
    <spring-data.version>1.10.4.RELEASE</spring-data.version>
    <cglib.version>3.2.5</cglib.version>
    <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
    <servlet-jsp-api.version>2.3.1</servlet-jsp-api.version>
    <commons-digester.version>3.2</commons-digester.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I've used latest spring version and updated few other dependencies.

Also in order to redirect to login page from index do the following:

```
.antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

Comment: @randikaisuru you're welcome. Just noticed that you wanted to redirect your app straight to login page from index if not authorized, so you have to use this: `.antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")`